# Array Guessing game - How to set and get an array?

Tags: java, arrays, getter-setter

I am trying to create a guessing game where the user enters a name and is

prompted to pick a number 5 times. I am trying to store the numbers in an array and use set and get methods to print out the attributes of the array. I have achieved this for the name but I am unable to set and get the array.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class StudentStore
{

    private String n1;//store's the player's name
    //private int [] s10;  //stores the player's score
    private int i;
    private int noOfPlayers = 5;
    private int[] s10 = new int[noOfPlayers];
    Scanner kboardIn = new Scanner(System.in);
    private int index;
    int newInt = 0;


    public StudentStore(String n1, int [] s10, int i )
    {

            this.n1 = n1;
            this.s10[i] = s10[i];
            this.setName(n1);
            //this.i = i;
            this.setScore(s10,i);
            //this.index = index;
        //  PlayerScore.incNumberScores();
    }

    public void setScore( int []s10, int i)
    {
        //takes an integer score, sets variables and checks topScore
        this.s10[i] = s10[i];
        //this.checkAndSetTopScore();
    }

    public int [] getScore()
    {

        return this.s10;
    }

    public void setName(String n1)
    {
        this.n1 = n1;
    }

    public String getName()
    {
        return this.n1;
    }
}

import java.util.Scanner;

public class StudentTester
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {

        Scanner kboardIn = new Scanner(System.in);

        int noOfStudents;

        System.out.print("Enter the number of students: ");
        noOfStudents = kboardIn.nextInt();
        //int[] noOfStudents;
        //noOfStudents = new int[100];




        StudentStore[] student1 = new StudentStore[noOfStudents];

        //int s1 = 0;
        int noOfPlayers = 5;
        int[] s10 = new int[noOfPlayers];
        //s10 = 0;
        String n1 = "something";
        int i = 0;

        for (int index = 0; index < student1.length; index++)
            student1[index] = new StudentStore(n1, s10, i);

            for (int index = 0; index <= student1.length; index++)
            {


                System.out.print("What is name of student no "+(index+1)+" ?");
                n1 = kboardIn.next();
                student1[index].setName(n1);
                System.out.print("What is mark for student no "+(index+1)+" ?");
                for(i=0; i < noOfPlayers; i++)
                {
                    s10[i] = kboardIn.nextInt();
                    student1[index].setScore(s10, i);
                    System.out.println("This is it" + s10[i]);
                }
                System.out.println(student1[index].getScore(      ));
                System.out.println(student1[index].getName());
                System.out.println(index);
                System.out.println(s10[index]);
                System.out.println(i);
                //System.out.println(s10[]);

            }




        for (int index = 0; index < student1.length; index++)

            System.out.println("\nTotal Mark for " + student1[index].getName()+ " is\t" + student1[index].getScore());

    }
}
```

Comment: You are already doing it?

Comment: would you suggest adding the iteration into the getScore() method? or in main? cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you want to know how to loop over arrays. This is how you could achieve it:

```
String[] strings = {"hi","yo","test"};
for(String s : strings){
   System.out.println(s);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

System.out.println(**student1[index].getScore()**); you are getting the array, but printing an array will not give stored values in array. You should iterate over the array and print seperatly all values.

Comment: would you suggest adding the iteration into the getScore() method? or in main? cheers

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the reply's. In the program System.out.println(student1[index].getScore()) is not printing a number. It is printing [I@137c6OD. I am not sure how to iterate over the array, but I will look up how to do it. Thanks a lot